# What are the functional differences in iLO 4 and iDRAC 7?

Tags: hp, dell, ilo, drac, server-settings

What are the functional differences in iLO 4 and iDRAC 7? Mainly in the working, features and what we can do with them. Please give a formal difference between them. It would be really helpful if you can mention the uniqueness in each of them.

Comment: What can we tell you that the documentation for these two products can't tell you? If you have specific technical questions about a feature, we can help, but we're not going to do comparative market research for you.

Comment: Not exactly market research but I want to know the special and unique features that each of them have. Documentations do explain about their products very well but don't point out on what is REALLY unique about them.

Comment: Well, for one thing, each only works in servers from the same vendor, and works best with the supporting infrastructure software from the same vendor.

Comment: So, show us that you've read the documentation and then explain what questions you still have.

Comment: Like :
1. iLO does need a license for extensive use iDRAC doesn't
2. Dell OMSA has interface to change uname/pass but HP needs CLI with XML
3. HP needs extra softwares installed(though comes in package), Dell   has one stop shop.
I NEED SOME MORE. 
@mfinni : But if you are not interested then you need not be rude and rag.

Comment: Read the help link at the top and you'll see why this isn't a good question for this site.

Comment: http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/ilo-demo/index.html - skip the video and you'll get a product comparison page (albeit skewed for HP for obvious reasons)

Comment: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ITRC-Remote-Lights-Out-Mgmt-iLO/HP-iLO-vs-Dell-DRAC/td-p/3917711#.Ur2ghbQkTq4

Answer (score 2):

Here's the documentation for both:

- Dell iDrac 7: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/white_papers/20065812.aspx
- HP iLO 4: http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/management/ilo/index.aspx

Read both for a full comparison. It'd be rather counterproductive to copy both texts here completely.

Comment: Thanks for the links, But I have already read what the documents say. But what I am asking here is the uniqueness in them, not the detailed functionality each of them do. Thanks.

Comment: The uniqueness? One is for managing HP servers and the other is for managing Dell servers. That is what makes them unique.